# Java and unlimited decimal places?

Tags: java, decimal, pi

Is there a simple way that i can manipulate high precision decimal numbers in java, without a limit on the number of decimal places, and the ability to output the number in a println or write it to a file? I want to work with one of the identities of PI that involves a sum of fractions, where k starts at 0 and goes to infinity. I know that most systems use limited decimals, but couldn't i use some pre-designed class which stores the value as a linked list of massive memory blocks if the number gets long enough? Please keep in mind i do need to do arithmetic with this class as well. Addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division should be sufficient.

Comment: http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/ if you don't mind using external libs.

Comment: For infinite precision you need infinite memory.  Also calculations on infinite precision also takes an infinite amount of time.

Comment: Agreed. However, i guess the point here is that i would be using as much of my available memory as possible. :) Good point on the time, i suppose ill expect this to be a program to run in the background for quite a while!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for the java.lang.BigDecimal class.

Comment: Thank you, i will have a look. :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at java.lang.BigDecimal, may solve your problem.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html